# Why the pseudocode have only one array for the DFS algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search

I read some of the DFS algorithms and find that these algorithms use only one array(stack) in their pseudocode.

[Depth First Search 1](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/depth-first-search/tutorial/)

[Depth First Search 2](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~heap/270F02/node36.html)

[Depth First Search 3](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/graph-dfs)

Assuming the graph is connected, I re-write the pseudocode as follows:

```
DFS(G, u)   (u is the vertex where the search starts)
Stack S := [];  (start with an empty stack)
List V := []    (an empty list for storing visited vertices)
V.push(u)
isVisited[u] := true
for all neighbours w of u in Graph G:
    S.push(w)
while (S is not empty):
    v := S.pop()
    for all neighbours x of v in Graph G:
        if x is not visited:
            S.push(x)
            isVisited[x] := true
```

I'm not sure if I'm correct or the other array can just be skipped.

Comment: Using a list (or strictly, a vector) to store visited nodes is inefficient because `vector.contains` is `O(n)` - and `contains` will be called `n`-times (giving you `O(n^2)` time complexity). Consider either marking nodes directly (such as using a wrapper) or using a HashSet - both of which have `O(1)` time complexity and `O(n)` space (if the HashSet is a Bloom Filter then it can be done in `O(1)` space if you don't mind a small statistical chance of false-positive "is visited" values).

Comment: If the graph is acyclic, such as a tree, then there's no need to track visited nodes separately from the stack because in DFS it's impossible to visit the same node more than once, so you only need one vector (used as a stack).